# How to send the CSV file through the POST request in Angluar, to a spring application?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

```
@ViewChild('fileImportInput') fileImportInput: any;

  fileChangeListener($event: any): void {

    const files = $event.srcElement.files;
    const studentsFile = files[0];
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('studentsFile', studentsFile, studentsFile.name);
    
    this.http.post('/api/enroll', { params: { batchId: `${this.batchId}`},  formData}).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

In the backend console, I'm getting this error **"Content type 'application/json' not supported]"**. I need to just upload and send the CSV as it is from the POST request to the backend. I am new to Angluar.

Comment: Can you share the "spring-boot" receiving side too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change this part

```
this.http.post('/api/enroll', { params: { batchId: `${this.batchId}`},  formData}).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

to:

```
this.http.post('/api/enroll', formData, { params: { batchId: `${this.batchId}`}}).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

`formData` is request body and it's the second argument to post function. Third argument are options.